# Get Each Item Price By Given Total Price And Item Rate (%)

Tags: excel, math, excel-formula, calculator

If we purchase some items with the bulk price let say:

1. Pencil 3 pcs
2. Watches 2 pcs
3. Drinking water 1 bottle

total price is $100 and we don't know the price for each item. How to get each price (per quantity) by adding rate (%) for every item.

### Rate |  Item

30%  |  Pencil
50%  |  Watches
20%  |  Drinking water

Higher Rate % mean higher price/qty.

Example calculation (Just to show Watch is more expensive):

1. Pencil: $12 * 3pcs = 36
2. Watch: $30 * 2pcs = 60
3. Drinking water: $4 * 1btl = 4

Total 36 + 60 + 4 = $100

Question: How to get item price ($12, $30, $4) based on % given?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Without the `Rate`s as you call them there is numerous combinations that could add up to $100. You can't deduce the `Rate`s with this much information. IF you have a few more rows that also have similar items then you might be able to as you can solve the simultaneous equations.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by rate? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_(mathematics) gives a general definition, but at least to me it's far from obvious what your percentage is denoting. Do you mean that 20% of the total sum was spent on the 1 bottle of water?

Comment: i mean price for 1 pcs of watch 50% higher.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the rates provided, you would have spent $30 on pencils, $50 on watches and $20 on Drinking water bottle.  We then need to divide the amount paid for each type of item by the quantity of that item (i.e. $30/3 pencils = $10), so we wind up with final prices of $10 per pencil, $25 per watch and $20 per drinking water bottle.